# Difference between Obj.Prop.AnotherProp and Obj.Prop?.AnotherProp

Tags: javascript

```js
var Obj = { Prop : { AnotherProp : "Hello World" } },
    log = console.log;

log( Obj.Prop.AnotherProp ) 
log( Obj.Prop?.AnotherProp ) // What does Prop`?` do?

// From Google Chrome and Node output is 
// Hello World
// Hello World
```

I am confused about calling Object Properties.

Comment: ? is to state that the field is optional not required.

Comment: `log(Obj.AnotherProp.Name)` vs. `log(Obj.AnotherProp?.Name)`